# small log server for callback posts in python

Tags: python

how can I build the same (like here in PHP ) in python 
to run on apache/nginx
the values will come as JSON

phpcallbacksave.php

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>Save http post</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
    print_r($_POST);
    $myfile = fopen("cbphp.log", "a");
    fwrite($myfile,print_r($_POST,true));
    fclose($myfile);
    ?>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you please add an example input and output and your current attempt? Not all Python programmers read PHP.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: like to store things like that
    curl -X POST -d "{'key1': 11, 'state': 1, 'stateName': xxxxxx', 'batteryCritical': xxxx}" "http://192.168.0.95/automation/phpcallback.php"
so JSON is in the POST
can't find where I get the content in a python variable

Comment: I'd suggest to look into [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).